# Socat: Allow reconnecting to a session

Tags: tcp, ssh, expect, socat

I can setup an SSH connection with a local PTY link - and I want to be able to send some triggers to the remote end, then use screen or minicom to connect to the session ie:

```
socat PTY,link=/tmp/foo,raw,echo=0 EXEC:"ssh otherbox"
```

Then in another window (or background the socat)

```
echo "securepassword|sudo -S bash"
screen /tmp/foo
```

The trouble is - after the echo, socat disconnects the EXEC - rather than keeping it open so that the PTY connection carries on.

Any ideas? (I can sort of do this with expect or empty-expect, but its a faf with the former and buffering screws up the latter for the interactive part of the session.)